# How to enforce a calling of a moving constructor (C++)?

Tags: c++, constructor, move-semantics

I have this couple of code-lines:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
  A() noexcept
  {
    cout << "A::A()" << endl;
  }
  A(const A&) noexcept
  {
    cout << "A::A(const A&)" << endl;
  }
  A(A&&) noexcept
  {
    cout << "A::A(A&&)" << endl;
  }
};

class B
{
public:

  B(const A& a) noexcept :
    _a(a)
  {}
  B(A&& a) noexcept :
    _a(a)
  {}

private:
  A _a;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  A a;
  B b1 = B(a);
  B b2 = B(A());
}
```

They produce this output:

```
A::A()
A::A(const A&)
A::A()
A::A(const A&)
```

What need I to do in order to the `A::A(A&&)` will be called from the `B::B(A&&)`?

As you can see adding `noexcept` does not solve this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although the *type* of `a` is an rvalue reference to `A`, `a` itself is an lvalue. To retain its rvalue-ness, you need to use `std::move`:

```
B(A&& a) noexcept :
  _a(std::move(a))
{}
```

Comment: Yea! Basically the same way will be using `static_cast<A&&>(a)` instead `std::move`.

Comment: Sure, but `std::move` is shorter, more idiomatic and works with `const`-qualified variables.

Comment: But it requires to include the `utility` header what is unwanted for me for purposes of use let's say one only call of the `move`. So there is some flexibility here.